# Set Default color value to angularjs color picker

Tags: angularjs, color-picker

I am trying to set default color value to my directive 
my div is

```
<div class="field">
   <color-picker ng-model="config.primaryColor"  options="options"></color-picker>
 </div>
```

Comment: add `ng-init = config.primaryColor = "myAwesomeColor"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put

```
$scope.config = {};
```

`$scope.config.primaryColor = '#FF0000';`

this will work I think

Comment: gives this error "Cannot set property 'primaryColor' of undefined"

Comment: is the config.primaryColor your scope variable?

Comment: For this to work you should set the ng-model as the scope variable

Comment: sure, in controller used this
$scope.config.primaryColor = '#425ba1";

Comment: This is because that the config property is not defined in $scope. You either use a $sope.SelectedColor as model object or define $scope.config  to fix it

Comment: add $scope.config = {} in scope to define it before initializing $scope.config.primaryColor

Comment: yes you are right i just removed that config property from $scope.config.primaryColor. So now its working

Comment: You can use $scope.config.primaryColor as itself by declaring  $scope.config before initialization.

Comment: Please Approve my answer if this is what your requirement is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127287/discussion-between-ajay-dixit-and-nitheesh).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should define `$scope.config={}` first then add to it the primary color